# Prolog query issue

Tags: prolog, declarative

Ok, let's say i have these two facts:

**data1([50, 20, 15, 20, 25, 20, 84]).
data2([50, 30, 15, 5, 10, 18, 60]).**

I want to make a query that asks whether the N-th element of the list defined as a part of those facts is some value.

query([L1|Tail]) :- L1 is 50. This would work but only if the query is like that - **query([50, 30, 20])**.. I want to ask something like **query(data1)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CapelliC's answer is correct, and he discusses why you should use the built-in `nth/3` or however it is called (`nth1/3` is actually not ISO, and not available in some implementations, like GNU-Prolog). I just want to add some clarification:

Your first issue here is that to ask a question, "does the Nth element of a list have a certain value", you need two arguments already: *N* and *Value*. Also, `is` is a predicate for evaluating arithmetic expressions and cannot be used for your purpose.

As for the `query(data1)`, you need some form of meta-calling....

In summary:

```
% query(Fact, N, Value) is true
% when the Nth element of the list argument of Fact is Value
query(Fact, N, Value) :-
    call(Fact, List),
    nth(N, List, Value).
```

and it can be called like this:

```
?- query(data1, 3, 15).
```

to query all `data1` facts that have one argument, a list.

Here `nth` should be defined as:

> nth(N, List, Value) is true when Value is the Nth element of List

but you should really rather use the built-in available in the implementation you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nth1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth1/3)/3 to access list elements by index.

Note in documentation that it's declared as `nth1(?Index, ?List, ?Elem)`. That question mark on a parameter indicates that that argument *could be* unbound. In other words, nth1/3 can work in several ways.

To get an element at index (1 based):

```
?- data1(L), nth1(2, L, V).
L = [50, 20, 15, 20, 25, 20, 84],
V = 20.
```

or to search positions where an element is:

```
?- data1(L), nth1(P, L, 20).
L = [50, 20, 15, 20, 25, 20, 84],
P = 2 ;
L = [50, 20, 15, 20, 25, 20, 84],
P = 4 ;
L = [50, 20, 15, 20, 25, 20, 84],
P = 6 ;
false.
```

It works as generally as possible, faithful to Prolog model where we don't have functions, but relations.

nth1/3 it's a relation between list elements and indexes.